# Which method will be used when it call itself inside?

Tags: python, class, methods, wrapper

In the code below, I overwrite `.append()` method of the `UserList`.
In the modified `append`, I first call the original `append` using `super`.
But the other code used `self.data.append(item)` rather than below.

```py
from collections import UserList

data = [4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 7, 3, 1, 0]

class ListSorter(UserList):
  def append(self, item):
    super().append(item) 
    self.data.sort()

sorted_list = ListSorter(data)

sorted_list.append(2)
sorted_list.append(-1)
print(sorted_list)
```

What I confused is this:

- Is it possible to call itself inside of the method?
- If it is possible, which one will be called, containers or overwrited one?

Comment: The code you wrote above seems fine to me because the output is a sorted list. This is what I was expecting. What were you expecting?

Comment: `sorted_list.append` is essentially just a wrapper around `sorted_list.data.append`, as you can see from [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1288). You could indeed call `self.data.append` directly instead of `super().append`, but there's little reason to break the abstraction provided by `UserLIst`. (Really, there's little reason to subclass `UserList` instead of `list` itself; `UserList` is mostly a relic from the days before `list` could be subclassed.)

Comment: @chepner there is still good reasons to use `UserList`, mainly, that it's methods returns instances of that `UserList`, and not `list`

Answer (score 0):

there is a very good introductory article about the difference between inheriting from pure *list* and **UserList**, which could be found [here](https://realpython.com/inherit-python-list/). The main point is that that the *UserList* has an additional attribute, which name is **data**. What the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) says about it :

> Class that simulates a list. The instance’s contents are kept in a regular list, which is accessible via the data attribute of UserList instances. The instance’s contents are initially set to a copy of list, defaulting to the empty list []. list can be any iterable, for example a real Python list or a UserList object.

In addition to supporting the methods and operations of mutable sequences, UserList instances provide the following attribute:

> **data**
> A real list object used to store the contents of the UserList class.

So back to your example, with only one small correction, which concerns the *.data*-attribute :

```
data = [4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 7, 3, 1, 0]

class ListSorter(UserList):
  def append(self, item):
    self.data.append(item)
    self.data.sort()

sorted_list = ListSorter(data)

sorted_list.append(2)
sorted_list.append(-1)
print(sorted_list)

#-->Result: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Attention:

There is a big downside of such approach and this is the the sorting, which will be executed on every append. It would make a big difference for a small list, but it doesn't scale good for bigger lists.

The time complexity of the sorting is O(n*log(n)) in the average case and this will be multiplied by the number of *appends*, which will make the appending from amortized O(1) (means could be O(n) in some cases where re-dimension of the list is needed) to O(n*log(n)).

Better approach in my opinion, would be to initialize and sort your initial data and then to use some build-in insertion as **bisect** for example, which will operate on the already sorted list and has O(log(n)) time complexity.

There are for sure even better approaches, which could be extended from some much more advanced users then me :)

Hope to have been of some help

Good luck !